# Is Metaphysics intended as a creative starting point?

Tags: metaphysics

Is Metaphysics intended as a starting point for ideas or perhaps a sort of hypothetical brainstorming scratchpad, with the intention that you must find a way to test any idea before it is regarded as meaningful and useful?  It seems to me that any idea that is not intended to potentially leave the area of metaphysics at some point is kind of pointless.

Comment: Not clear... a starting point of what ? [Metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics) is a traditional topic of (at least) Western philosophy, since Aristotle.

Comment: Metaphyscis is a way to work out the (most likely) truth about Reality. At its best it is a science of logic. As you say, metaphysical results that cannot 'leave the area of metaphysics' (in the sense of having no ramifications beyond metaphysics) would be useless. But it is inevitable that such results have global ramifications. .

Comment: My advice is to treat metaphysics as first-principles. What is existence? What is truth? What is value? And as you answers grow more sophisticated, so too does your metaphysics.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A starting point of a solution to a problem.  All human thought is about problem solving.